# Create nested object structure from flat one

Tags: javascript, object, nested, structure

If anyone can tell me please how can I do from this flat object structure:

```
mainObj = {
    "Ob1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ob1",
        "properties": {
            "attName": "A1",
            "attType": "string",
            "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
        },
    },
    "Ob2": {
         "id": 101,
         "name": "Ob2",
         "properties": {
             "attName": "B1",
             "attType": "string",
             "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
         },
     }
     "Ob3": {
          "id": 10001,
          "name": "Ob3",
          "properties": {
              "attName": "C1",
              "attType": "string",
              "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
              },
     }
}
```

To this one nested in another object, but with the data of the flat one:

```
myObj = {
    "Ob1": {
        "myObjName": "A1",
        "myObjType": "string",
        "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
        "Ob2": {
            "myObjName": "B1",
            "myObjType": "string",
            "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
            "Ob3": {
                "myObjName": "C1",
                "myObjType": "string",
                "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
            } 
        }
   }
}
```

The nesting logic is, if the next object's id is bigger than the previous one, then is it's child.
This is the logic:

```
for each(var obj in mainObj){
    switch (true) {
        case  obj.id < 100: levelId=1; break;
        case  obj.id < 10000: levelId=2; break;
        case  obj.id < 1000000: levelId=3; break;
        case  obj.id < 100000000: levelId=4; break;
    }
}
```

I have just this, but I don't know how to nest them:

```
for (key in mainObj) {
    myObj.myObjName = mainObj[key].properties.attName,
    myObj.myObjTyp = mainObj[key].properties.attType,
    myObj.myObjOcc = mainObj[key].properties.attOccurance
}
```

Please if anyone can tell me how can I do this?

Comment: To make it more clear. Can you pls add 4th object with id 202 and tell what's the output

Comment: btw, how do you access the inner objects? how do you know its name?

Comment: 1. If id 202 appears, it will be on the same level as 101 like in the example.
2. Nina, don't know the inner objects name, but I suppose the for cycle can check if there is an object, right?

Comment: why not take the children into a children array?

Comment: Can you please give me an example what do you mean?

Comment: why is `Ob4` not a child of `Ob2`?

Comment: I added the switch case logic, to be more clear

Comment: do you have to use this structure?

Comment: The new one in myObj? Yes, I have to print it afterwards, but first I need the nested structure so that I can know the childs and parents

Comment: why is `202` not sorted under `2` (which is not given)? whereas `10001` is sorted under `101`, which should be better `100` ... in this case all numbers, better strings starts with their parent string.

Comment: In practice, there will never be 202, because it will be 102, 103... max until 120

Comment: @unknownDev Pls see my answer, if it helps. Will add explanation, if you want and if it caters your need.

Comment: come on, why do you use some id who are not in reality? it makes hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I didn't use it initially, there was a person that asked for that case

Comment: Well I was the person who asked for it and it was for clarity as only 3 inputs were not making clear how result should be handled and so I needed some more input data.

Comment: @unknownDev can you pls check my answer by clicking "Run Code Snippet" and let me know you get your expected result?

Comment: I understand, the thing is that is complicated case, because it's used in a bpm tool, it's older version of js and the input are objects translated into js from uml diagrams :/

Comment: @NitishNarang, yes, that is the expected result, thank you. I will import it into the tool and check it.

Comment: Sure @unknownDev.

Comment: @unknownDev, can we consider 1 in 'ob1' as level 1, and 2 in 'ob2'  as level 2 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input and output this is what I have come up with. See if it helps.

Though there were many cases I thought that I am not sure what the output should be.

```js
const mainObj = {"Ob1": {    "id": 1,    "name": "Ob1",    "properties": {        "attName": "A1",        "attType": "string",        "attOccurance": "minOccurs='1'"    },},"Ob2": {     "id": 101,     "name": "Ob2",     "properties": {         "attName": "B1",         "attType": "string",         "attOccurance": "minOccurs='1'"     }, }, "Ob3": {      "id": 10001,      "name": "Ob3",      "properties": {          "attName": "C1",          "attType": "string",          "attOccurance": "minOccurs='1'"          }, }, "Ob4": {      "id": 202,      "name": "Ob4",      "properties": {          "attName": "D1",          "attType": "string",          "attOccurance": "minOccurs='1'"          }   }}

let levelKey = {}, newObj = {}

function getLevel(id) {
  let level = 1
  while(parseInt(id / 100) > 0) {
    level++
    id = id / 100
  }
  return level
}

function getLastLevel(id) {
  id--
  while(id > 0) {
    if(levelKey[id]) return id
    id--
  }
  return id
}

function getObj(str) {
  return str.split('.').reduce((o, d) => o[d], newObj)
}

for( let [k, v] of Object.entries(mainObj)) {
  let level = getLevel(v['id'])
  let obj = {
    myObjName: v.properties.attName,
    myObjType: v.properties.attType,
    myObjOcc: v.properties.attOccurance
  }

  let lastLevel = getLastLevel(level) || level
  levelKey[lastLevel]
    ? (getObj(levelKey[lastLevel])[k] = obj, levelKey[level] = levelKey[lastLevel] + '.' + k)
    : (newObj[k] = obj, levelKey[level] = k)
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the idea behind getLastLevel(id) function?

Comment: `getLastLevel` method is to get which level we need to add the current object to. So, if current obj is at level 2 and you pass to this method it returns `1` means this object should be inside 1st object.

Comment: I will inform you, I need to simplify the solution a little bit, because some of the methods/functions are not recognized. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Go ahead!! Let me know if you need any other clarity.

Comment: if it's not too much trouble for you, can you please tell me what can I use instead of "reduce" function and "Object.entries(mainObj)", because I work on older version of JavaScript and these are not recognized and I don't have the possibility to import js libraries

Comment: Okay, you want alternate for both `reduce` and `entries`, right?

Comment: Though `reduce` is already in older versions, so it should not be an issue I think.

Comment: Instead of `Object.entries` you can directly loop, and you have to change it like - for( let k in mainObj) { var v = mainObj[k],...

Comment: That’s great!! This one really took a time to think of!! A good problem to solve